# 7W IC amplifier

Tags: power-supply, amplifier, audio, function-generator, spectrum-analyzer

I have a 7W Audio Amplifier IC Module. It's instruction says power input should be 12~16 Volts. The audio source should be connected to "IN" and "G". Output should be a 7W Speaker to "SPK". In lab, I'm supposed to only use the provided lab equipment, a function generator, spectrum analyzer, and lab power supply. I would like to know can I use the function generator as a audio source and the spectrum analyzer as SPK output, to see the output of the amplification?

Comment: Is this a trick question?

Comment: No, absolutely not. I am just wondering can I perform those tasks with spectrum analyzer and function generator?I need someone to confirm that these can be done

Comment: Audio is just an infinite sum of sine waves. Can you view both source and output on the analyzer at the same time?

Comment: I can use sweep in function generator to generate sine waves with different range of frequencies but I wonder how to use spectrum analyzer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your information is lacking detail but I will try to answer your question. A function generator is an audio source when its frequency is set to an audio frequency (generally defined as 20-20000 Hz).  The waveshape should be set to sine. Connect the high output lead of the generator to IN and the low end to G.  The power supply should be set to the mid value specified (14 volts).  For a 7 watt linear amplifier, the power supply will probably have to supply at least twice that power but assume three times or 21 watts. Therefore the supply should be rated for at least 21/14 or 1.5 amperes.  If you don't have a speaker, then use a resistor.  Again I will assume the amplifier is designed to drive an 8 ohm load so you will need an 8 ohm resistor capable of dissipating at least 7 watts, 10 watts would be preferable. The spectrum analyzer can then be connected across the resistor. If you need more specific information, you will have to provide more information about the specifications of your amplifier.

Comment: Thanks I added the picture of instruction of IC amplifier. It says I should supply 12-16 DC volt but you told me 14 or 21. Can you explain about this? Also spectrum analyzer can tolerate maximum 1 W when I connect 7W and 10W resistor does this mean that I should add 20dB attenuator? Also How do you know which one is high output or low output lead of function generator since both looks the same one is black the other one is red. Thanks

Comment: I said to set the power supply to 14 volts and the amplifier may draw 21 watts. The 1 W maximum on the spectrum analyzer is the power limit into the analyzer.  It is not the power being dissipated by the load resistor.  You need to know the input impedance of the analyzer and the maximum voltage out of the amplifier to calculate the power into the analyzer.  If that exceeds 1 W then use the attenuator.  In most cases the red lead is the high and the black lead is ground.